# MariaDB / MySQL: index structure for table with one value column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have a MariaDB MyISAM table with three columns:

```
`time` int not null, 
`sensor` tinyint not null, 
`value` decimal (6,4) not null
```

Also I have a PRIMARY KEY (BTREE) on the columns `time` and `sensor`

The table has 250 million rows and 20 new records are added every 10 seconds. All SELECTS on the table have a WHERE clause either on just `time` or on `time` and `sensor`.

This works well performance wise but the index uses even more disk space than the table itsself (2.2GB for the data and 2.7GB for the index). This seems a bit silly to me as the index is basically the entire table, which means that MariaDB has essentially doubled all data.

Is there a better structure for this table?

Comment: elasticsearch ? :D

Comment: What index?  The PK handles both types of `WHERE`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Do use `InnoDB`, not MyISAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire point of database indexes is to trade space for time. Yes, it's normal for indexes to take roughly as much space as the table, especially when the table has short rows like yours does.

If you switch to the InnoDB storage engine your primary key will become a so-called *[clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html).* That is, the entire table will be contained within the primary key's index. That can save a lot of disk space.

You should switch to InnoDB: MyISAM is a legacy storage engine that's not getting much attention from MariaDB's developers.  If for some reason InnoDB doesn't work for you, switch to the more modern Aria storage engine. It is similar to MyISAM. Like MyISAM, it doesn't use a clustered PK index.

Notice this: Your primary key is on `(time, sensor)`.  That means it's best suited to where clauses that look like this:

```
 WHERE time BETWEEN start AND finish
```

If you remade your primary key so it were on `(sensor, time)` it would be suitable for

```
 WHERE sensor=somesensor AND time BETWEEN start AND finish
```

Why? MySQL random-accesses the BTREE index to the first eligible row, then scans it sequentially to the last eligible row. You can read about this multi-column index stuff [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html).

So, your choice of primary key column order should be based on which of those two `WHERE` patterns is more performance-critical: time-range only or sensor and time-range.

If this were my table I'd define it like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE series (
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    sensor SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    value DECIMAL(6,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    PRIMARY KEY (sensor, time) USING BTREE,
    INDEX time_covering (time, sensor, value) USING BTREE
) COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This table definition offers a [clustered primary key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html) optimized for filtering by sensor then time range. And I have added a covering index (basically a copy of the table) optimized for filtering by time range only.  For information about covering indexes see the last section of [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

It uses a `TIMESTAMP` data type. They're just as efficient at representing time as integers, and you get the benefit of time arithmetic. This gets you yesterday's readings from sensor 3.

```
WHERE time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND time < CURDATE()
  AND sensor = 3
```

It uses a `SMALLINT` rather than a `TINYINT` for sensor number. You're less likely to run out of sensor numbers, and `TINYINT` data only helps save space when there are several of them in each row.

Comment: 99% of selects are ```WHERE time BETWEEN x AND y and sensor IN (a,b,c,d)```. But the time clause is extremely selective (the time-range is about 6 years and usually the time clause in the where is 1 hour)

Comment: Then you'll get a small improvement by switching to the `(sensor, time)` index order, and you probably don't need the `time_covering` index I suggested. You'll get an improvement from innodb

Comment: @final - Aha!  There is a significant Optimization between `sensor=3` and `sensor IN (...)`.